# How to json normalize columns in vaex?

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

Given a nested json, is there a way to load and flatten it in vaex?

This is a way to do it in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_json(input_file)
df = pd.concat([df, json_normalize(df['eventData'])], axis=1)
```

The json could be something like this:

```
[
{"timestamp":..., "id": ..., "eventData": {"type":..., "name":...}},
{"timestamp":..., "id": ..., "eventData": {"type":..., "name":...}}
]
```

And the dataframe's columns should be "timestamp", "id", "type" and "name".

Comment: If you transform the data slightly, you can probably use `vaex.from_dict()`, no?

Comment: @AMC Not really sure what you mean. `from_dict` expects a dictionary, not a list of dictionaries which is what `df['eventData']` is. In pandas I could also use `from_records` and `concat` with `axis=1` (ie ```df = pd.concat([pd.read_json(f), pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['eventData'])], axis=1)```) but none of those are available in vaex.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: If you can already do this with pandas, why not just do `vaex_df = vaex.from_pandas(pandas_df)` ?

Comment: @Joco This issue with doing `json_normalize` in `pandas` is the memory usage.  On large datasets with large JSON data in a column the function does not complete in `pandas`

Comment: @rchitect-of-info indeed, so in that case one will need to resort to chunking the file, and export smaller manageable bits to hdf5 or arrow, and open them all at once with vaex.